# Layout Override shows up as menu Item but not as category layout

Tags: overrides, template-override, layout, category

I have created a layout override starting from the blog template and added it in 
mytemplate\html\com_content\category :

```
galleries.php
galleries_item.php
galleries.xml
```

I can create a new menu item with this layout and it works great.

I need to override the layout for a specific category but this new layout type does not show up in the "Alternative Layout" dropdown. I see only "From Global Options" and "From Component", but no layouts from my template (or any other template).

What should I do to also be able to set this layout as category alternative layout?